# How to reload a webpage without reloading Java Script again?

Tags: javascript, html

Purpose : For Google Ads

I need to reload a page without loading js content ( which will be in file) as JS will be bigger in size it will get loaded only for first time and for next page reloads only dynamic content ( like ads , dynamic text) will keep on changing. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Browsers usually cache your javascript files, so you shouldn't have to worry about download times too much. If you're talking about the time it takes for your javascript to run, then you may be out of luck. You can't save the state of a javascript runtime for later.

Comment: Use the HTTP caching directives to control when JS files are retrieved from the server and when they are retrieved from the browser cache.

Comment: How are you serving your static files vs your dynamic files ?

Comment: @SaintGerbil: i am unclear about your question, Dynamic file will contain some variables whose values will keep on changing on each page load.The plan is , first load 100 values , once user want to go ahead of 100 , load next 100 values ,for this range js will be constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. You can make sure that the JS file can be cached by sending the appropriate HTTP headers to the browser.
2. If users stay a long time on your site and work with it like a desktop app, you can create an initial page and load the JS once. If you convert all links to send AJAX requests which just replace the content part of the page, the JS won't be loaded again because you never "leave" the page.

Answer (score 7):

Most browsers cache JavaScript and CSS files as long as the name of the file hasn't changed since last time the page was accessed.

Also, if file size is an issue, consider minifying your JS and CSS files. This compresses the files using various techniques while keeping the same functionality. There are various online tools for doing this, my favorite being [Online YUI Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/).

Answer (score 6):

If on Linux you can use the .htaccess file e.g:

See:

http://www.samaxes.com/2008/04/htaccess-gzip-and-cache-your-site-for-faster-loading-and-bandwidth-saving/

This works great.

Mathias

Answer (score 1):

Or you can refresh dynamic content using Ajax

http://www.markvoss.net/scripts/ajax.asp

That's an option